# Botium can't find partial convo in my test spreadsheet

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot

Trying to run a botium test with partial convo in excel but failing with:

> Error: Cant find partial convo with name Roaming_TCs_Partial.
>
> (Roaming_TCs_Partial is the name of partial convo)

- Excel has test case in one tab and partial convo in another tab
- `Roaming_TCs_#Side_Question` tab has the test case with reference to partial convo implemented as `INCLUDE Roaming_TCs_Partial` under ME section
- `Roaming_TCs_Partial` tab has the steps for partial convo with `Roaming_TCs_Partial` at the beginning of the conversation under ME section
- Test failed with:

  > Error: Cant find partial convo with name Roaming_TCs_Partial.

NOTE - Excel format settings for the test set has the `Roaming_TCs_Partial` updated against `Excel contains partial convos` setting.

Not sure why botium is still unable to find the partial convo. Wish I was able to attach my excel file and a screenshot of my settings but I dont see an option to upload files here. Help in getting this resolved is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note - If this is not the right place to post this issue, please suggest me the correct way of posting such posts in stackoverflow so i can follow the right process going forward. Appreciate if any botium users who successfully managed to get resolution to their posts without  been closed  can help me with this bit too pls.

I expect the test to pick up the partial convo and pass
But the test failed with:

> Test failed with "Error: Cant find partial convo with name Roaming_TCs_Partial".

Comment: Hi, to emphasize the code or program values use this symbol " ` " not this " ' ". On the keyboard you can find it at the left from " 1 " key.

Comment: you can attach screenshots with copy&paste

Comment: @Bulat & Florian - Thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48922649/Composing+in+Excel+files) you can find a sample for using partial convos from Excel files.

Partial convos are placed in their own worksheet:

[image]

And you can reference them in the convo with the *INCLUDE* clause by worksheet name and Excel cell reference:

[image]

*UPDATE*

Corrected your excel sheet in your test set (TOBI_POC_KT) on the trial server.
* The question/answer convos have to be in separate lines - happened in the partial convos that first answer was in same row as the question
* there is only one empty row allowed between the convos, otherwise botium will stop reading

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing the above sample code. After implementing the above, I no longer see the `Cant find partial convo` error however receiving the error [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/390/0H9X38.jpg)

Here are the screenshots of convo and partial convo files. 
Partial convo - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/6613/Hermku.jpg)
Convo - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/9550/XhEi2v.jpg)

Comment: 2) Test with reference to the second partial convo in the Roaming_TCs_Partial tab
please find this convo in tab > Roaming_TCs_#Side_Question2 of the [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2430/wDbCst.jpg)
Actual result - `Error: Cant find partial convo with name Roaming_TCs_Partial-D9`

Link to both convos errors in botium  - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3135/H59DYR.jpg)
Link to Partial Convo - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/6613/Hermku.jpg)

Comment: 3) Test with user utterance in ME section followed by INCLUDE clause (basically replicated your sample convo)
please find this convo in tab > Roaming_TCs_#Side_Question3 of the [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/6443/nTEt3n.jpg)

Link to both convos errors in botium  - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/3135/H59DYR.jpg)
Link to Partial Convo - [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/6613/Hermku.jpg)

Comment: OK, the Excel file is slightly incorrect formatted. Will provide you a corrected one shortly.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I shall wait for the correct format.

Comment: Can you please advise when can we expect the corrrect format? Thanks.

Comment: see TOBI_POC_KT in trial

Comment: Awwww! That's a silly mistake! Thank you Florian. My test is successful now :)

Comment: While I can get partial convos to work on trial edition, they are unfortunately failing on community edition :( 
I've tried partial conversation in Botium Community edition (local machine) and it gave me the below error:

Comment: error sending to bot TypeError: Cannot read property 'intent' of undefined at BotiumConnectorWatson._processWatsonResponse (/app/agent/node_modules/botium-connector-watson/dist/botium-connector-watson-cjs.js:252:26) at handleResponse (/app/agent/node_modules/botium-connector-watson/dist/botium-connector-watson-cjs.js:221:20) at BotiumConnectorWatson.UserSays (/app/agent/node_modules/botium-connector-watson/dist/botium-connector-watson-cjs.js:242:11) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

Comment: But when I replicate it on the trial version, it works perfectly fine. All test set excel file and settings are identical. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This bug is part of the Botium Watson connector and has been fixed in the latest Botium Box 1.7.4 only (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-watson/commit/4e6745e0e7a64a8f2d0cd061aaddd5f95db114bb)